# Why is my Django, jQuery, Ajax like button liking all posts?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-templates

I am attempting to make a twitter like social media feed in a Django ListView and have added an Ajax like button from the *Django 3 By Example* book. The like feature works perfectly in the DetailView but I cannot get it to work in the ListView. When hitting the like button in the DetailView it likes all of the posts on the page and will show 1 like, then 11110 likes, then goes up exponentially from there. The toggling of like/unlike is correct but does not reduce the count by 1; it just keeps going up. Please help!

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage(), upload_to = pics_path, blank=True, null=True)
    vid = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage(), upload_to = vids_path, blank=True, null=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='posts_liked', blank=True)
```

Views.py:

```
@require_POST
def post_like(request):
    post_id = request.POST.get('id') 
    action = request.POST.get('action') 
    if post_id and action:
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id) 
            if action == 'like':
                post.users_like.add(request.user) 
            else:
                post.users_like.remove(request.user) 
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
        except: 
            pass
    return JsonResponse({'status':'ko'})
```

Template aka post_list.html:

```
{% with total_likes=post.users_like.count users_like=post.users_like.all %}
    <div class="post-info"> 
        <div>
            <span class="count">
            <span class="total">{{ total_likes }}</span>
            like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
            </span>
            <a href="#" data-id="{{ post.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like" class="like button">
            {% if request.user not in users_like %} 
            Like
            {% else %}
            Unlike
            {% endif %}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

jQuery:

```
    var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken'); 
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method)); 
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }   
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.like').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.post('{% url "like" %}',
                {
                    id: $(this).data('id'), 
                    action: $(this).data('action')
                },
                function(data){
                    if (data['status'] == 'ok') 
                    {
                    var previous_action = $('a.like').data('action');
                    // toggle data-action
                    $('a.like').data('action', previous_action == 'like' ? 'unlike' : 'like');
                    // toggle link text
                    $('a.like').text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like');
                    // update total likes
                    var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text()); 
                    $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
                } 
            }
        ); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are selecting all `a.like` elemnents on the DOM, same for `span.count.total`

You should be more specific when selecting, ideally using id. For example in the `<a>`:

```
<a href="#" id="{{ post.id }}" data-id="{{ post.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like" class="like button">
```

Then in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.like').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var action = $(this).data('action');
            $.post('{% url "like" %}',
                {
                    id: id, 
                    action: action
                },
                function(data){
                    if (data['status'] == 'ok') 
                    {
                    var previous_action = $('#' + id').data('action');
                    // toggle data-action
                    $('#' + id).data('action', previous_action == 'like' ? 'unlike' : 'like');
                    // toggle link text
                    $('#' + id).text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like');
                    // update total likes
                    var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text()); 
                    $('#' + id + '_total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
                } 
            }
        ); 
    });
});
```

Same for the span elements. Keep in mind that you should use **unique** id for each element, so maybe you could append suffix like `id="{{ post.id }}_like"`, `id="{{ post.id }}_count"`, `id="{{ post.id }}_total"` to differentiate.

Comment: My template now looks like: ```<span class="count" id="{{ post.id }}_count">
                                <span class="total" id="{{ post.id }}_total">{{ total_likes }}</span>
                                like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
                                </span>
                                <a href="#" id="{{ post.id }}_like" data-id="{{ post.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like" class="like button">```. Is that correct? I've tried every variation of what you suggested for my jQuery but still no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: I overlooked, but  seems that the `id` its not in the scope of the post success callback. I've edited the answer to reflect a possible approach. Hope it helps!

Comment: Trying that just removes the liking functionality alltogether and makes page reload to the top.... Likes it is following the link to #. Any other suggestions? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to debug without more details, have you tried looking at the console, to check which part is triggering the page reload?
It should follow the # in the link because of the preventDefault, and if it does, it shouldn't trigger a page reload, maybe a scroll to the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
AJAX CODE 
<script>
    $("a.btn-like").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Button CLicked");
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(id);
        mydata={
            id:id
        };
        mythis=this;
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '{% url "like_post" %}',
            data : mydata,
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data.likes);
                $('#'+id).text(data.likes);
            }
        })
    })
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container mb-5 mt-4">
      {% for p in posts %}
       <div class="card mx-auto mt-4 col-sm-8">
           <p class="display-6 lead">Title : {{p.title}}</p>
           <span class='p-2'>
            <a href="" id="btn-like" name='btn-like' data-id="{{p.id}}" value='{{p.id}}' class='text-decoration-none  mb-2 btn-like' ><span id="{{p.id}}">{{p.likes}}</span> 
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up mb-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8.864.046C7.908-.193 7.02.53 6.956 1.466c-.072 1.051-.23 2.016-.428 2.59-.125.36-.479 1.013-1.04 1.639-.557.623-1.282 1.178-2.131 1.41C2.685 7.288 2 7.87 2 8.72v4.001c0 .845.682 1.464 1.448 1.545 1.07.114 1.564.415 2.068.723l.048.03c.272.165.578.348.97.484.397.136.861.217 1.466.217h3.5c.937 0 1.599-.477 1.934-1.064a1.86 1.86 0 0 0 .254-.912c0-.152-.023-.312-.077-.464.201-.263.38-.578.488-.901.11-.33.172-.762.004-1.149.069-.13.12-.269.159-.403.077-.27.113-.568.113-.857 0-.288-.036-.585-.113-.856a2.144 2.144 0 0 0-.138-.362 1.9 1.9 0 0 0 .234-1.734c-.206-.592-.682-1.1-1.2-1.272-.847-.282-1.803-.276-2.516-.211a9.84 9.84 0 0 0-.443.05 9.365 9.365 0 0 0-.062-4.509A1.38 1.38 0 0 0 9.125.111L8.864.046zM11.5 14.721H8c-.51 0-.863-.069-1.14-.164-.281-.097-.506-.228-.776-.393l-.04-.024c-.555-.339-1.198-.731-2.49-.868-.333-.036-.554-.29-.554-.55V8.72c0-.254.226-.543.62-.65 1.095-.3 1.977-.996 2.614-1.708.635-.71 1.064-1.475 1.238-1.978.243-.7.407-1.768.482-2.85.025-.362.36-.594.667-.518l.262.066c.16.04.258.143.288.255a8.34 8.34 0 0 1-.145 4.725.5.5 0 0 0 .595.644l.003-.001.014-.003.058-.014a8.908 8.908 0 0 1 1.036-.157c.663-.06 1.457-.054 2.11.164.175.058.45.3.57.65.107.308.087.67-.266 1.022l-.353.353.353.354c.043.043.105.141.154.315.048.167.075.37.075.581 0 .212-.027.414-.075.582-.05.174-.111.272-.154.315l-.353.353.353.354c.047.047.109.177.005.488a2.224 2.224 0 0 1-.505.805l-.353.353.353.354c.006.005.041.05.041.17a.866.866 0 0 1-.121.416c-.165.288-.503.56-1.066.56z"/>
                  </svg>
               </a>
           </span>
       </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

PYTHON

```
def like_post(request):
    id=request.GET.get('id')
    print(id)
    post=Post.objects.get(pk=id)
    post.likes+=1
    post.save()
    return JsonResponse({'likes':post.likes})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).